# Does OAuth0 Java APIs support AES algorithm encryption

Tags: oauth-2.0, aes, auth0, caesar-cipher

Does OAuth0 Java APIs support AES encryption?
I am looking [Auth0 Java APIs](http://92%20bit%20add%2010-20%25%20off%20extra%20overhead%20as%20computation%20and%20number%20of%20rounds%20of%20substitutions%20increases.) and I could not find AES encryption.

Answer (score 0):

No, OAuth does not support AES encryption. You can find the supported algorithms in the [JSON Web Algorithms (JWA)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518) specification (section 3.1)

Comment: It seems you have misunderstood the question. The question is about OAuth0 Java Library for OAuth 2.0

Comment: Can you fix the link in the original question? You mean Auth0 Java API?